# Yesod migrations on existing PostgreSQL databases: ALTER vs. DROP

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod

After a few months, I am updating an existing service + db built using Yesod+Persistent, and running into a problem with the migrations.

In the past, I always got the following migrations during a deploy, which worked fine.

> ALTER TABLE "collected_highway" ALTER COLUMN "admin_unit" TYPE varchar(8);
>
> ALTER TABLE "collected_highway" ALTER COLUMN "date" SET DEFAULT Now(); []

But now I am suddenly receiving the following

> ```
> ALTER TABLE "collected_highway" ALTER COLUMN "admin_unit" TYPE varchar(8);
> ```
>
> *** ALTER TABLE "collected_highway" DROP COLUMN "date";

This happens with existing PostgreSQL databases for the app, even if I delete the contents of the column.

Note that it does not happen in my local environment via "stack exec yesod devel", even when using the same remote database.

Here is the model in question.  It has not changed for quite a while.

```
CollectedHighway
  highway     Highway
  userId      Int64
  highwayId   Int64
  adminUnit   Text sqltype=varchar(8)
  date        UTCTime default=Now()
  UniqueCH    userId highway
```

yesod-bin version: 1.5.2.3

Any idea why I am getting a DROP instead of an ALTER all of a sudden?  It's a problem because it requires manual intervention, and will probably cause data loss.